# How to set size and location of JButton in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton

I'm trying to set the size and location of a button on a panel using setBounds. It works when I put the button on the frame and have setLayout(null). But when placed on the panel, the button is always a set size at the top of the panel, if I set the layout to null, the frame just shows up blank.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    
        MyFrame cl=new MyFrame("A"); 
        
        cl.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    }
}
```

```
import java.awt.*;  
import java.awt.event.*;  
  
import javax.swing.*;  
public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
      MyPanel panel;    
      Container cont;
      JButton b;
      
      
      
      public MyFrame(String title) {
          super(title);
          
          panel= new MyPanel();
          
          b = new JButton();
          b.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 100 );
          
          cont= this.getContentPane();
          cont.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
          cont.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
          panel.add(b);
          
     
          
          this.setLayout(null);
          this.setVisible(true);
          this.setSize(1000,1000);
         
      }

}
```

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    
    public MyPanel() {
        
    }
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }

}
```

Comment: My strong suggestion is to use LayoutManager's. They are there to help programmers. You can use nested JPanel's with differing LayoutManagers to place things where you want them.

Comment: Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Why would you attempt to position a button at (100, 100) of a frame that is (1000, 1000)? Don't use random numbers. Generally layout is done by specifying requirements like 1) centered horizontally or 2) centered vertically or 3) centered both horizontally/vertically. Once you have an actual requirement then you use the appropriate layout manager and the button will automatically be positioned even when the frame size changes. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: Is the button all that will appear in this GUI view? Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* (complete) layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.